# How to set 3 displays as follows: primary, mirror of primary and secondary?

Tags: gnome3, display-settings, display-manager

The current setup of my displays is as follows:
[image: current_setup]

I would like the `2nd Sony` display to be a mirror of `3rd Dell` display, while the `1st Samsung` display should remain as separate secondary display.
When I try to change `2nd Sony` display into `Mirror` mode, the button `Apply` is grayed out:
[image: grayed_out_button_when_in_mirror_mode]

Is there a way to make it the way I want it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using xrandr

Overlapping screens can be achieved by changing their position using the following command:

```
xrandr --output (screen indicator) --pos (x coord)x(y coord)
```

Example:

```
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --pos 0x768
xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --pos 0x768
```

This results in `DVI-D-0` screen being at the top and `HDMI-0` with `DVI-I-0` being at the bottom, overlapping.

You can find out screen's indicator using:

```
xrandr -q
```

## NVIDIA X Server Settings

The required behaviour can also be achieved using NVIDIA X Server Settings.
Simply drag and drop the screen's box onto each other for them to operate in a mirror mode.

[image]